# Recovering conversation data from State data in bot framework

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-table-storage

We have an applications bot where a user fills a form and then it gets sent to an API. Problem is that API service provider  implemented a new feature and a new error couldn’t be raised.

Now we have 10 applications missing and we would like to recover the records

All conversation data is stored on a Storage Table. We see al the records. But the data is encoded.

If we follow some of guidelines to recover the data column we can deserialize into a class with a few parameters and the chat state itself (Dialogstate in the JSON obj) is still encoded.

Decoded byte[] from Data column in Table:

```
 {
  "ResumptionContext": {
    "locale": "sv",
    "isTrustedServiceUrl": true
  },
  "DialogState": "H4sIAAAAAAAEAO1b3W/bVBSPW8dN.....more data
```

This is where we are stuck. There seems to be quite some data there and we are confident that the forms are still there but need guidance decoding or accessing the bot object.

Comment: Were you storing the user data inside ConversationData / PrivateConversationData or UserData?

Comment: You did deserialize **Data property**, what is your actual scenario that need to decode **DialogState**?

Comment: Hi @NicolasR, op might query all data from a storage table that he configured as BotDataStore, not just query based on `{channelid}:conversation` etc.

Comment: @FeiHan sure, but did the op store anything on that (not only the automatic storage of BotData)? If that's not the case, it will be difficult to access these data, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, based on my experience, it would be difficult to access these data.

Comment: Different type (and structure) of data could be stored in ConversationData, it will be very difficult when we deserialize to original type (or structure) and extract these data.

Comment: Hello. The data is stored acording to Microsoft doc. So the automatic state data. The data is on every row but in webchat:private is Where the large data chunks are.

Comment: I cant find any info om deviding the data further. The Only thing incand think of is if I as a developer could start a dialog a “user” that I want to retrieve information from. Then in the code implement methods to access the contex.conversation data.

Comment: After much reading I doubt any dialog data is stored. Maybe conditional data but I think is mostly state data for the dialoflow. I have now implemented tablebotstorage in the global.ax file, and it creates a new table with a new structure. Where all the dialogs are stored

Comment: The DialogState isn't encoded, but compressed.  There's a lot of autofac registered classes involved, but it comes down to this: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/89ca8267072b3ea4eb31fa5c7432b27e4bf77b67/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Fibers/Store.cs#L63

Comment: Yes. The first datachunk on the storage table I compressed. After decompression I get what I posted above. Is the Dialogstate also compressed?